# Proper abstraction for cons'ing and uncons'ing with laws

Tags: haskell, typeclass, abstraction, cons

There exist several data structures that support `cons` operation — adding element at the beginning of this structure:

- `(:)` for lists
- [`(<|)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Sequence.html#v:-60--124-) for `Data.Sequence`
- [`cons`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text.html#v:cons) for `Data.Text`

All those data structures also have `head` and `tail`. So I want to create abstraction (using type class) that covers all such possible types with polymorphic operation in order to use use `head`, `(:)` and `tail` for any data type that implements this type class. Moreover, I want some laws for this type class.

I wonder, is there any good existing abstraction that allows destructuring into *head* and *tail* and prepending an element?

Something really close to this:

```
-- Foldable is used because I can have and may use
-- head :: Foldable f => f a -> Maybe a

class Foldable f => Prependable f where
    (:)  :: a -> f a -> f a
    tail :: f a -> f a
```

Comment: Obviously more than you are looking for, but this sort of thinking usually ends up in [`IsSequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.2/docs/Data-Sequences.html#t:IsSequence).

Comment: I think `uncons :: f a -> Maybe (a,f a)` as the inverse of `cons` seems natural and would allow you to write both `head` and `tail` depending on how `tail` is defined for an empty structure.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! Your comments are really useful and helpful. I just wasn't aware about all existing implementations of these concepts. Now things more clear for me.

Comment: @Alec The real goal for me actually is not to implement some containers interface but to implement `(:)` pattern using `-XPatternSynonyms` for every data type. It requires `uncons` function mentioned by @ryachza .